# boost interprocess managed_windows_shared_memory grow()

Tags: c++, boost, interprocess

Is it possible to grow and shrink managed_**windows**_shared_memory?
I'm try example for managed_shared_memory from [boost doc](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_35_0/doc/html/interprocess/managed_memory_segments.html#interprocess.managed_memory_segments.managed_memory_segment_advanced_features.growing_managed_memory) and it's work.

```
//Now that the segment is not mapped grow it adding extra 500 bytes
managed_shared_memory::grow("MyManagedShm", 500);
```

But when my "MyManagedShm" is windows-native serment, program just freeze. If I write

```
managed_windows_shared_memory::grow("MyManagedShm", 500);
```

compiler says

```
no matching function to call
```

with note

```
couldn't deduce template parameter 'ManagedMemory'
```

and show me candidate that fits perfectly:

```
template<class ManagedMemory>
   static bool grow(const char *filename, std::size_t extra_bytes)
   {
      typedef typename ManagedMemory::device_type device_type;
      //Increase file size
      try{
         offset_t old_size;
         {
            device_type f(open_or_create, filename, read_write);
            if(!f.get_size(old_size))
               return false;
            f.truncate(old_size + extra_bytes);
         }
         ManagedMemory managed_memory(open_only, filename);
         //Grow always works
         managed_memory.self_t::grow(extra_bytes);
      }
      catch(...){
         return false;
      }
      return true;
   }
```

I can't find any info in boost docs that this in not possible in windows. Maybe in windows I need to force unmap segment before grow or shrink? I can't find how to do this as well.

If I write

```
#include <boost/interprocess/managed_shared_memory.hpp>
#include <boost/interprocess/managed_windows_shared_memory.hpp>
using namespace boost::interprocess;

int main() {
     { managed_windows_shared_memory msm(open_or_create, "mmap", 400); } 
     //{ managed_shared_memory::grow("mmap", 65535);             } 
     { managed_windows_shared_memory msm(open_only, "mmap");           } 
}
```

It throw "file not found" on second open.

Comment: what does "when it is a windows native segment" even mean? It should not be *open* at the time of the grow, obviously

Comment: Stop trying to look for workarounds, it should not "freeze".  If you find a workaround then it is just going to freeze again.  Disable anti-malware first.  Next use a debugger, enable the symbol server, show us the stack trace.

Comment: I think it freeze because I call grow() in the same {}-space (I dont know how it's calling in english) so segment was mapped. If I do it right - it throws exception. I think because of "windows_shared_memory has no kernel persistence and the shared memory is destroyed when all processes destroy all their windows_shared_memory objects and mapped regions for the same shared memory or the processes end/crash."
And now I'm confused: does {}-space have own processes?!

Answer (score 0):

What does "when it is a windows native segment" even mean? It should not be *used* at the time of the grow, obviously.

Also, the "perfect match" overload will **never** deduce the template argument, because it's not used in the signature.

So you'll always have to explicitly instantiate.

Proof of concept:

**<kbd>[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/e6423cd73b709445)</kbd>**

```
#include <boost/interprocess/managed_mapped_file.hpp>
using namespace boost::interprocess;

int main() {
     { managed_mapped_file mmf(open_or_create, "mmap", 400); } 
     { managed_mapped_file::grow("mmap", 65535);             } 
     { managed_mapped_file mmf(open_only, "mmap");           } 
}
```

**<kbd>[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/14a1bcdb0fa6c452)</kbd>**

```
#include <boost/interprocess/managed_shared_memory.hpp>
using namespace boost::interprocess;

int main() {
     { managed_shared_memory msm(open_or_create, "mmap", 400); } 
     { managed_shared_memory::grow("mmap", 65535);             } 
     { managed_shared_memory msm(open_only, "mmap");           } 
}
```

Comment: "when it is a windows native segment" mean managed_windows_shared_memory that have difference from portable managed_shared_memory (using pagefile, lifetime difference).